# How to keep a multi-line nested bullet list indentation (and bullets if possible) when pasting from Google Docs to emacs

Tags: indentation, text-editing, copy-paste, formatting

I copy a nested list like this:

```
- foo
  - bar
    - foo
    - bar
```

from Google Docs to emacs, but the bullet points vanish and the indentation as well. The same happens in the normal Linux text editor.

How can I keep the nested list structure when pasting in emacs? The bullet points may vanish, but if they can be kept, for example as dashes, they are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the file as "Plain text (.txt)" to get the a list with bullet points and indentation.

```
    1st level:
        * 2nd level
            * 3rd level
                * 4th level
                * b
                * c
                * d
        * a
            * b
                * c
                * d
                * e
    x:
        * y
        * z
```

If you do not want to download a whole file and search for the right start and end, you can also use for example Freeplane Mindmap: paste it into a node and the list will become a mindmap. If you copy that mindmap into a text editor afterwards, it will have the needed structure.